# Download multiple OSM data key and value pairs via Graphical Modeler in QGIS

Tags: qgis, openstreetmap, qgis-modeler, quickosm

I want to download OSM data from a query in an extent via the Graphical Modeler in QGIS.
Thereby I want to download multiple keys and values at once, but it somehow only takes the first one or none.

Let's take the example of primary, secondary and tertiary streets.

[image]

The modeler states that multiple keys can be asked by adding the seperator ',' in between each key and value. I tried several versions with spaces an without, but it only downloads the first key and value pair or none.

Outside the modeler I can add multiple keys and values with Or and it works within QuickOSM.
[image]

Any idea how I can replicate that inside the model builder without having three individual downloads? Thanks!

Comment: Can you tell us a little bit more about the workflow? Which algorithm do you use in the modeler - the one called `Donwload OSM data from a query in an extent` in your screenshot? Where do you see the information that the modeler states that multiple keys can be asked by adding the seperator

Comment: Can you share your model? I also can't see how you get the output (`Streets`) - fragmentary information about you workflow makes it more difficult to address your problem. I don't have the option `Output file`: https://i.stack.imgur.com/VpjN0.png

Comment: @Lucas_Edenhofer can you please tell us how you were able to use Download OSM data from a query in the Model Designer.  This algorithm does not appear in the algorithm list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use semicolon `;` to delimit the different values, which are enclose in single quotes `'`. Don't repeat the key if it is the same for all values.

Then try using either

1. With the default `Value` setting and the string `'primary';'secondary';'tertiary'`

   or
2. with setting `Pre-calculated Value` and the string `eval ('"primary" or "secondary" or "tertiary"')`

[image]

Comment: Second option with worked.

Comment: Hi @Lucas_Edenhofer, I'm trying to do the same thing but can't get it to work.  Please can you post your model or some screenshots?