# Model Designer - Available Algorithms

Tags: qgis, openstreetmap, qgis-plugins, query

Is it possible to add an algorithm from the Processing Toolbox to the list of available algorithms in the Model Designer? Looking at the question [HERE](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/460790/download-multiple-osm-data-key-and-value-pairs-via-graphical-modeler-in-qgis?rq=1),  I see that they are in the designer and are using the algorithm *Download OSM data from a query in an extent*, but I am not seeing this in the algorithm list in the designer.
[image][image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe they modified the plugin QuickOSM because by default the algorithms in the toolbox aren't available in modeler and those in modeler aren't available in toolbox.
They have a flag set depending on where they are supposed to be used by using the flags [`QgsProcessingAlgorithm.FlagHideFromModeler` and `QgsProcessingAlgorithm.FlagHideFromToolbox`](https://api.qgis.org/api/classQgsProcessingAlgorithm.html#a6a8c21fab75e03f50f45e41a9d67dbc3)

Algorithms available in the modeler are:
[image]

I guess you could bypass this restriction by modifying the code of the plugin to remove the relevant flags.

Otherwise there is [this tutorial](https://docs.3liz.org/QuickOSM/user-guide/processing/) on how to use the modeler algorithms the way they are intended. (it contains an explanation and also an example model at the end of the page).